# React client requests don't reach node js server, nginx

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, nginx, deployment

I am trying to deploy my react node js app and I am having this bug:

When the react client makes a request to http://localhost/server/profile, it doesn't reach the server, and when I go manually to http://[IP]/server/profile it works.

essentially, when I use REACT_APP_REMOTE_SERVER_URL="http://[IP]:50000/server" it works, and when I use REACT_APP_REMOTE_SERVER_URL="http://localhost/server", it doesn't (I get request failed)

How do I fix it so the request that the react client makes reaches the server correctly?

nginx config:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  location / {
        root /var/www/app/client;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }

  location /server {
        proxy_pass  http://localhost:50000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}
```

Part of server.js:

```js
const express = require("express");
const { corsConfig } = require("./controllers/serverController");
const app = express();
const helmet = require("helmet");
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(helmet());
app.use(cors(corsConfig));
app.use(express.json({ limit: '0.30mb' }));
app.use(cookieParser());

// Add "/server" prefix to routes
app.use("/server", authRouter);
app.use("/server/Profile", profileRouter);

console.log("node env: ", process.env.NODE_ENV);
const port = 50000;
server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`);
});
```

I disabled the firewall, changed the .env remote_url variable to many things like "/server" and checked that CORS config is correct. Still same error.

Comment: I see that your port is 50000, But you're making a request to http://localhost/server/profile, where your port is not specified,. Try making request to http://localhost:50000/server/profile

Comment: @BrokenDetector I am making tge request to localhost/server/profile hoping that nginx will forward it to the server.

Comment: If you make a request to `http://localhost/server/` without specifying a port, the default port would be assumed. The default HTTP port is 80, and if you're running your Node.js server on port 50000, you should specify the port in the URL.

Comment: @BrokenDetector, 1) nginx will proxy the requests from port 80 to port 50000. 2) requests to http://localhost:50000/server/profile don't work. The only way to make requests work is to put the IP instead of local host (example: http:[IP]/server/profile)